# HTML 5 <nav> Centering

Tags: html, nav

I am simply trying to center a `<nav>` bar at the bottom of an HTML page, and obviously I'm missing something, as there are many answered questions on this subject, but none of them seem to work for me. I don't think I'm doing anything spectacularly different, but it doesn't work. My `<nav>` bar always shows up on the left half of the page.

Note that the `float:left;` in the  `nav.footer li` below makes the individual `li` float next to each other. If my understanding is correct, it should not make the whole group of them float to the left of the page.

[A fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzq8X/)

```
<head>
<title>Fake</title>
<style>
nav.footer
    {
        color:red;
        width:700px;
    }
nav.footer ul
    {
        float:left;
        display: inline-block;
        list-style-type: none;
        color:green;
        font-size:20px;
    }
nav.footer li
    {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 9px 20px 4px; 
        background-color:#DDDDDD;
        border-left:1px solid #112233;
        border-right:1px solid #112233;
        border-top:2px solid #112233;
        border-bottom:2px solid #112233;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<br>
    <div>
        <nav class="footer">
            <ul>
                <li>1 <a href="#">Batman</a></li>
                <li>2 <a href="#">Superman</a></li>
                <li>3 <a href="#">Ironman</a></li>
                <li>4 <a href="#">Thor</a></li>
                <li>5 <a href="#">Hulk</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Obviously, I'm still learning.

Comment: can you add a fiddle.

Comment: @Rider Not sure what that is.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net. Add your code in "html" text area, tap "Save", copy link from address bar.

Comment: Why are you floating your UL at all? Are you intending on putting another float in this element?

Comment: Create a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/ by adding your html and css. save it and paste your link here.

Comment: @Diodeus It makes the individual entries cram together like I want.

Comment: Also, fiddle is awesome.  http://jsfiddle.net/Lzq8X/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
nav.footer{
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: This works. Why do I need to add it? I don't understand and would like to.

Comment: It has a display block, the nav it is. So in order to center a block element, you need to add auto margins on left and right. Think the `margin:0 auto` as: `margin-top: 0; margin-right: auto; margin-bottom: 0; margin-left: auto;`.

Answer (score 1):

What's lacking from your code:

```
nav{width:100%; /* 100% width of the parent container */ }
nav>ul{list-style-type:none;/*still leaves margin and padding*/
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to nav.footer:

```
 margin:0 auto; // or margin:auto
 margin-bottom:30px; //change this value as you want
```

`margin:0 auto;` or `margin:auto;` centers your nav. 
`margin-bottom:30px;` margin from bottom - 30 pixels.

Comment: This works. Why do I need to add it? I don't understand and would like to.

Comment: 1) ok, accept my answer 2) to solve your problem - nav centering 3) You could remove 0, it is only means that no margin from center

Answer (score 1):

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Animeshjain/2Ez5e/)

add this to your css

```
nav.footer{
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: This works. Why do I need to add it? I don't understand and would like to.

Comment: adding this centers your nav bar.

Comment: Sure, of course. But why must the margin be 0 to center it? I wouldn't have guessed that. I would have guessed that I could apply a margin of any size and have it centered (albeit with my margin added into the calculation). I guess I don't understand the linkage between `margin:0` and centering working.